# Drupal simplenews doesn't subscribe the users registed via social networks

Tags: emails, social-network

I'm using [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module for sending newsletter to the registered users. When a user creates a new account he/she will be automatically subscribed to a newsletter which can be seen in **admin/people/simplenews**.

However, when user registers via social network he/she is not subscribed to newsletter. When I visit **admin/people/simplenews** I can see only the users registered in normal way; users registered through a social network cannot be seen.

I'm using [HybridAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) for Twitter & Google+ login and [Fboauth](https://www.drupal.org/project/fboauth) for Facebook login. In simplenews configuration, I've used **silent** setting. What can I do to make users sign up to a newsletter on social network registration?

Answer (score 1):

The reason users aren't signed up is due to how simplenews works. It does the work of newsletter signup by modifying the [Drupal core registration form](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/simplenews/tree/simplenews.module?h=7.x-2.x#n1007) to capture the newsletters (or setting them automatically in case of the silent option) then takes that data to sign users up [following account creation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/simplenews/tree/simplenews.module?h=7.x-2.x#n1055).

For both HybridAuth & FBOauth, they subvert this process with their own forms to do authentication with a 3rd party. Both HybridAuth & FBOauth however, provide their own API hooks to take action upon user registration ([`hook_hybridauth_user_insert()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/hybridauth/tree/hybridauth.api.php?h=7.x-2.x#n116) & [`hook_fboauth_user_save()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/fboauth/tree/fboauth.api.php?h=7.x-2.x#n112) respectively). You can implement their hooks in a custom module to do the same work HybridAuth does to [signup users automatically](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/simplenews/tree/simplenews.module?h=7.x-2.x#n1079).

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solution with help of instructions given in the above answer. I just simply called the `simplenews_subscribe_user()` inside [hook_hybridauth_user_save()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/hybridauth/tree/hybridauth.api.php?h=7.x-2.x#n116).

```
function my_module_fboauth_user_save($account, $fbuser) {
  simplenews_subscribe_user($account->mail, 15, $confirm = FALSE, $source = 'automatically', NULL);
}
```

I don't whether this method is a correct procedure to solve above problem. But it works for me.